# Computing mean for average running pace (using two different pandas dfs)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have two sample data frames, and I'd like to compute the mean of each running pace (the `Avg. Pace` columns). These are represented like so: 5:57, 6:07, etc. I have converted them from an object, which I have found onerous:

```
previous_week = previous_week.astype({"Distance":'float64', "Runs":'int64', 'Avg. Pace':"datetime64", 'Elev. Gain':'int64'}) 
previous_week['Avg. Pace'] = previous_week['Avg. Pace'].apply(lambda y: str(y))
previous_week['Avg. Pace'] = previous_week['Avg. Pace'].apply(lambda y: datetime.strptime(y, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%H:%M'"))

current_week = current_week.astype({"Distance":'float64', "Runs":'int64', "Avg. Pace":'datetime64', 'Elev. Gain':'int64'})
current_week['Avg. Pace'] = current_week['Avg. Pace'].apply(lambda y: str(y))
current_week['Avg. Pace'] = current_week['Avg. Pace'].apply(lambda y: datetime.strptime(y, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").strftime("%H:%M'"))
```

These give me the format I'd like (e.g., 5:57), but still will not allow me to calculate the mean of the two `Avg. Pace` columns, when tested on the `current_week` data:

```
current_week['Avg. Pace'] = current_week['Avg. Pace'].apply(lambda y: pd.to_datetime(y))
df_mean = current_week['Avg. Pace'] - current_week['Avg. Pace'].min().mean() + current_week['Avg. Pace'].min()
```

I get `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mean'` or `AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'mean'`. I'd really like to stop converting back and forth - it is tedious. How do I get the average running pace of each `Athlete`, across each data frame?

Sample data:

```
current_week = {'Athlete': {0: 'John M.', 1: 'Tyler L.', 2: 'Matt J.', 3: 'Ben S.', 4: 'Tom C.', 5: 'Tucker C.', 6: 'Jordi P.', 7: 'Robert P.'}, 'Distance': {0: 21.4, 1: 19.4, 2: 16.1, 3: 10.8, 4: 8.3, 5: 6.4, 6: 5.9, 7: 4.8}, 'Runs': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 2, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 1}, 'Avg. Pace': {0: "06:19'", 1: "05:24'", 2: "04:55'", 3: "05:18'", 4: "07:19'", 5: "05:01'", 6: "05:16'", 7: "05:00'"}, 'Elev. Gain': {0: 524, 1: 45, 2: 4, 3: 81, 4: 67, 5: 67, 6: 34, 7: 53}}

previous_week = {'Athlete': {0: 'John M.', 1: 'Tyler L.', 2: 'Andrew L.', 3: 'Matt J.', 4: 'Ben S.', 5: 'Tom B.', 6: 'Robert P.', 7: 'Tucker C.', 8: 'William M.', 9: 'Tom C.', 10: 'Jordi P.', 11: 'Nick M.'}, 'Distance': {0: 70.3, 1: 43.7, 2: 42.3, 3: 32.2, 4: 31.6, 5: 22.6, 6: 22.0, 7: 18.9, 8: 15.4, 9: 14.9, 10: 13.5, 11: 1.9}, 'Runs': {0: 5, 1: 3, 2: 3, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 2, 6: 3, 7: 3, 8: 2, 9: 3, 10: 3, 11: 1}, 'Avg. Pace': {0: "05:57'", 1: "05:31'", 2: "05:47'", 3: "05:07'", 4: "05:43'", 5: "05:12'", 6: "04:52'", 7: "05:00'", 8: "04:48'", 9: "07:43'", 10: "09:48'", 11: "05:04'"}, 'Elev. Gain': {0: 1298, 1: 211, 2: 199, 3: 31, 4: 255, 5: 118, 6: 214, 7: 151, 8: 89, 9: 96, 10: 101, 11: 12}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming average pace is never greater than 00:59:59. If that is not the case please let me know.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(current_week)
# strip that extra ' at the end of the string
df['Avg. Pace'] = df['Avg. Pace'].str.strip("'")
# to_tmedelta to average pace column but add '00:' to get %H%M%S format
df['Avg. Pace'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:'+df['Avg. Pace'])
# get the mean
df['Avg. Pace'].mean()

# Timedelta('0 days 00:05:34')
```

Or if you do not care about converting the time in the column to a `timedelta` then just use `numpy.mean` directly on the list created from the `map` function

```
df = pd.DataFrame(current_week)
# strip that extra ' at the end of the string
df['Avg. Pace'] = df['Avg. Pace'].str.strip("'")
# convert to %H:%M:%S
np.mean(list(map(pd.to_timedelta, '00:'+df['Avg. Pace'])))

# Timedelta('0 days 00:05:34')
```

If you want to group on athlete for both weeks we `concat` our frames and use `groupby`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(current_week)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(previous_week)

big_df = pd.concat([df,df1])
big_df['Avg. Pace'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:'+big_df['Avg. Pace'])
# dictionary comprehension for each group
d = {a:d.mean() for a,d in big_df.groupby('Athlete')['Avg. Pace']}

{'Andrew L.': Timedelta('0 days 00:05:47'),
 'Ben S.': Timedelta('0 days 00:05:30.500000'),
 'John M.': Timedelta('0 days 00:06:08'),
 'Jordi P.': Timedelta('0 days 00:07:32'),
 'Matt J.': Timedelta('0 days 00:05:01'),
 'Nick M.': Timedelta('0 days 00:05:04'),
 'Robert P.': Timedelta('0 days 00:04:56'),
 'Tom B.': Timedelta('0 days 00:05:12'),
 'Tom C.': Timedelta('0 days 00:07:31'),
 'Tucker C.': Timedelta('0 days 00:05:00.500000'),
 'Tyler L.': Timedelta('0 days 00:05:27.500000'),
 'William M.': Timedelta('0 days 00:04:48')}
```

If you want to see the mean for John M. you would just do `d['John M.']`

Or if you prefer to create a frame instead of a dictionary

```
l = [[a, d.mean()] for a,d in big_df.groupby('Athlete')['Avg. Pace']]
mean_df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Athlete', 'Average Pace'])
```

Comment: Which one is the most "pythonic" way? And everyone in this data frame is thankfully not that slow!

Comment: I'm also trying to get the average for each runner, across the two data sets. I.e. if John M had 5:57 and then 6:10, what's the total average for just him

Comment: @papelr see update in the answer for how to groupby athlete from both datasets

Comment: I'm getting a `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "TimedeltaArray") to str
` on the `big_df['Avg. Pace'] = pd.to_timedelta('00:'+big_df['Avg. Pace'])` line. Should I get rid of the original conversions up above in my question?

Comment: @papelr that is correct, remove the original conversion. That line works directly with string dtypes

Comment: I realllllyyyyyyy had to wrangle that one, but your way worked, eventually. Had to put these lines in: `df_pace['Avg. Pace'] = df_pace['Avg. Pace'].apply(lambda y: str(y))` and 
    `df_pace['Avg. Pace'] = df_pace['Avg. Pace'].str.replace(r'0 days', '')` - but got to the same answer you had

Comment: @papelr you can avoid the apply, which is slow in nature, by doing `d = {a: str(d.mean().to_pytimedelta()) for a,d in big_df.groupby('Athlete')['Avg. Pace']}` so essentially just change `d.mean()` in the comprehension to `str(d.mean().to_pytimedelta())`